# How to parse integer for decimal text

Tags: java

I have the below requirement:

1. input `String = "1.00000"` should be converted to int ( because actually no fraction at all )
2. input `String = "1"` should be converted to int 1
3. however, input `String ="1.0001"` should be an Exception (because has fraction )

Previously I was assuming `Integer.valueOf("1.00000")` should return an integer.However it returns `NumberFormatException`.

any Java library that can solve this, or at least can check if 1.0000 is actually an integer so I can safely parse as Double and cast it to int?

Comment: `1.00000` is **never** an `int`.

Comment: Who gave you these requirements, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `BigDecimal` class

Java itself has a library that does exactly this: [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Example:

```
private static int parse(String input) throws ArithmeticException {
    return new BigDecimal(input).intValueExact();
}
```

The [`intValueExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValueExact()) method throws an `ArithmeticException` if the `BigDecimal` object has a non-zero fractional part.

Comment: This is really the best answer. I had to delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

One way to tackle the problem is, you can use regex to first ensure that the input exactly matches the format of a number with fractional part being optional and if at all then all being zeroes and if yes, then go ahead and parse it else throw Exception or whatever you want to do. Check this Java code,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1.00000","1","1.0001");
Pattern intPat = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(\\.0+)?");

list.forEach(x -> {
    Matcher m = intPat.matcher(x);
    if (m.matches()) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(num);
    } else {
        System.out.println(x +" is not a pure Integer"); // Throw exception or whatever you like
    }
});
```

Outputs,

```
1
1
1.0001 is not an Integer
```

Also, as long as the numbers you are working with are confined within integer range, its all good but to ensure the numbers don't cross integer limit, you may want to use a different quantifier.

Another alternate simpler solution you can go for is, parse the number as double and compare it with its int form and if both are equal then it is a pure integer else not. I'll prefer this than my first solution using regex. Java code,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1.00000","1","1.0001");

list.forEach(x -> {
    double num = Double.parseDouble(x);
    if (num == (int)num) {
        System.out.println((int)num);
    } else {
        System.out.println(x + " is not a pure Integer");
    }
```

Prints,

```
1
1
1.0001 is not a pure Integer
```